# Angular leaks memory with a massive amount of detached nodes (using entryComponents)

Tags: javascript, angular, memory-leaks, angular2-template

I've got a simple app that uses `entryComponents` with `ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory` to inject components depending on the data at a very high rate. I use `viewContainerRef.clear();` and every injected component has a OnDestroy methode. As far as I know my code does not leak anything (unsubscribing to every observable when destroyed) but why is angular keeping all these detached nodes in the memory?

I use a lot of ngIf, ngFor, ngClass etc. I think the garbage collector should just throw these unused nodes away. But he doesn't.

Does anyone know what I should look for? Or is my basic assumption wrong that clear should be taking care of this? If so how do I manually call OnDestroy and remove the component?

[image: Chrome's memory snapshot analysis]

Comment: I was using Component Factories following this guide https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: It is probably related to this plugin I use inside the injected template https://github.com/murhafsousli/ngx-gallery

Comment: did you manage to solve this @bb1? I have the same question

Comment: @habit I found other sources of memory leaks and could eliminate most of it. It was not related to entryComponents at all. I still had a few KB leaking which may still origin from entryComponents but it wasn't the big 200MB increase that you see here.